# Replicate the changes in all stages of a release pipeline in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a multistage release pipeline which has about 15 stages for different environments. If I make a change to one of the steps in a stage I have to replicate it to each stage manually. Is there a way I can choose multiple stages and make the change?

Comment: In the all stages all the jobs/steps are the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use task groups for that:

> A task group allows you to encapsulate a sequence of tasks, already
>   defined in a build or a release pipeline, into a single reusable task
>   that can be added to a build or release pipeline, just like any other
>   task. You can choose to extract the parameters from the encapsulated
>   tasks as configuration variables, and abstract the rest of the task
>   information.

that would allow you to create a template and modify it and it will get modified everywhere its being used.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/task-groups?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 1):

Regarding this issue, there was feedback from users earlier. You can refer to this user voice ([Manage multi-stage release pipeline](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/379178/manage-multi-stage-release-pipeline.html)) about the same issue on our Developer Community forum.

One way is that you delete the previous stages and then clone the modified stage, but I think this is not what you want because the release history is lost and it is tedious to re-clone every change.

So, agree with **4c74356b41**, if you want a way to easily insert a number of stages into release pipelines (keep the defiinitions consistent) and to enable these stages to all be updated in one operation, use [task groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/task-groups?view=azure-devops) is a good solution . You could add all of your tasks to a task group and then only using the task group in your stages. If you make changes to a task group, all stages that use that task group should be updated as well.

If the task group does not meet your needs, you could vote that suggestion ticket and share your comment there ,leave your specific needs in the comments.The product team would provide the updates if they view it.